# I have existing HTML code inside a MACRO which was working fine, I added a row & I get Expected: line number or label or statement or end of statement

Tags: excel, vba

I have existing HTML code inside a MACRO which was working 100% fine, I added a row and ensured all the syntax are matched, I have also selected Tools->References->Microsoft Internet Controls, Microsoft  HTML Object Library.
All the code has turned red and I get the below error:

Compline error:

Expected: line number or label or statement or end of statement

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: [Without code, it is very hard to help you](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/)